# Tenor Sax compilation with a Gato Barbieri tune

Tags: jazz, compilations

My bus driver once lent me an album that was a compilation of tunes by great jazz tenor sax players, and I fell in love with a cut done by Gato Barbieri.  I seem to recall it was a 2-album set, and it might have been the second or third cut on the first side of the first album was the one I was thinking of.  It was not new when he lent it to me in 1979, so I'm guessing it was released in early-mid 70's?  I can't recall either the album or the name of the cut, or what cassette tape I have it recorded to.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://loami-windmill.com/Music/gato_barbieri.mp3 That's the tune, but I still have no idea what it's called or what album it came from.

Comment: More progress, the tune is called "To Be Continued" although all the versions on YouTube are shorter (by at least half.)  I still don't know the compilation where I found it though.

Comment: Did you take a look on discogs ?  this is the album which apparently first had the song, ["Chapter one - Latin America"](https://www.discogs.com/Gato-Barbieri-Chapter-One-Latin-America/master/68310). The discography there has many compilations, but nothing that I could see with "To be Continued"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song that you're looking for has a very convoluted history.

The track that you heard is "Encontros (parts 1 & 2)" from the Foundations compilation released on Impulse records in 1978: 
https://www.discogs.com/Tom-Scott-John-Klemmer-Gato-Barbieri-Foundations/release/3145070

There are two different versions of Encontros on that Foundations compilation [the live version is found on side 2 (Montreux 07/06/73); the studio version is found on side 3 (recorded in Rio DeJeneiro 04/28/73)]. I'm assuming that the version that you are interested in is the studio version. [If the live version is what you want, skip to the last 2 sentences of this post.]

Gato has recorded multiple versions of this song. On his Chapter One album, the song is titled "Encuentros"; on Chapter Two the version was now called "Encontros".

---

The studio version of Encontros (Parts 1 & 2) found on side 3 of the Foundations compilation is taken from the recording sessions for this album:
https://www.discogs.com/Gato-Barbieri-Chapter-Two-Hasta-Siempre/master/303126

The version of "Encontros" found on the Chapter Two album was *not* the version found on the Foundations comp. Both versions were different edits of the same recording. The Chapter Two version is titled "Parts 1 & 3". The Foundations version was "Parts 1 & 2". To confuse things further, a third edit of Encontros was found on this Impulse compilation:
https://www.discogs.com/Various-The-Saxophone/release/4802595

---

The unedited performance (12 min) of Encontros was first made available on this 1997 compilation:
https://www.discogs.com/Gato-Barbieri-Latino-America/release/13264655

This long version was originally chopped up to make the Part 1 & 2 version (found on the Foundations comp) as well as the Part 1 & 3 version (found on Chapter Two). The mix on the unedited version is *slightly* different... but it seems to be the exact same performance. You can re-create the Foundations version of the track by fading out the unedited version at about 6 minutes.

---

In regard to the track titled "To Be Continued" found on Chapter One:

Chapter One and Chapter Two were recorded in Rio DeJeneiro during the same month. Chapter One's leadoff track was "Encuentros". The final track on Chapter One was listed as "To Be Continued": *That was never intended to be the title of the song*. Two weeks after recording Chapter One, *Gato recorded a second version of "Encuentros"* intended to be part of Chapter Two. As Chapter One was being prepared for release, producer Ed Michel included a bit of this second version at the end of Chapter One as a *teaser* for Chapter Two. That teaser featured a spoken intro by Gato and was titled "To Be Continued". Inclusion of that track was a way of saying, "here's a taste of the next chapter".

By the time Chapter Two was released the following year, the second version (which had originally been heard on "To Be Continued") had been amended to include an *additional* electric bass part as well as extra percussion. The spoken intro was also removed. The track (in effect, version 2a) was now titled "Encontros". The track heard on Foundations was an edit of this track.

---

I'm willing to send you digitized versions of the live and studio versions of Encontros found on the Foundations comp (as well as the unedited track). Let me know how to reach you.